# Is there any way I can hide the get request response from browser when I send it from nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am sending a `get request response` from `nodejs` to `reactjs` thorugh a url. But whenever I paste the url directly in the browser, all the content gets displayed on the browser. Is there any way I can hide the content from the browser?

```
  app.get('/purchase', function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true },  
    function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db(process.env.DB_NAME);
      dbo.collection("TableStatus").find({}).toArray(function(err, 
      result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(result);
      });
    });
  });
```

So whenever I enter `http://localhost:4000/purchase` directly in the browser, `result` gets displayed. Is there any way to redirect it to main page or maybe hide the content from the browser?

Comment: This is a potential use-case for a `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

Longer answer, depends. You can try to obscure the request with headers or query params, but still clients can always learn about how the request is sent to your server, and mimic exactly how your app communicates with the server. So still no, you can't hide it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If the assumption is that you only want your application to call that endpoint and not make it available to the general public, then you could use basic authentication on that endpoint. There is the [express-basic-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth) middleware which would work. You can require that endpoint to only accept requests if they contain the correct `Authorization` header params (which your application would use) and redirect any other request which does not meet those specs.

There are other ways which would involve rolling your own checksum system, but I believe using basic auth is likely the easiest.